# PdfPCell NoWrap=true overflows width of the PdfPTable

Tags: c#, itext

When I set a PdfPCell's property `NoWrap = true`, if the text inside the cell is wider than the table, it overflows the width of the table. I have a 36f margin, and I set the `table.WidthPercentage = 100f`, and that is working fine. But if I put a long string of text in a cell with `NoWrap = true`, it goes all the way to the very edges of the document. Is there any way to keep the text in the cell from going outside the width of the table?

Here is my code:

```
customFont = FontFactory.GetFont(defaultFontName, 22, Font.BOLD);
string vehicleName = vehicle.Name;
Phrase vName = new Phrase(vehicleName, customFont);
vName.Leading = 22f;
table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.SpacingAfter = 10f;
table.WidthPercentage = 100f;
cell = new PdfPCell(vName);
cell.Border = 1;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
cell.NoWrap = true;
cell.Padding = 0;
table.AddCell(cell);
document.Add(table);
```

And when this displays on the document, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the text is overflowing the border of the cell. I guess I just assumed that if the cell was NoWrap, it would fill up the cell, then stop when it couldn't show any more. Maybe that's not possible.

Or any other ideas on how to make a one-line title that can never wrap to more lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `NoWrap` on the cell set the `FixedHeight` to the cell's height. This will cause the cell to overflow the content but not show it as you want.

Comment: I was originally using `FixedHeight`, but when doing so, it was adding a strange amount of space or padding above the text that I could not get to go away. As you can see in [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/cW9Jk6k.jpg), I set the cell's border to 1, and I drew the line to the border. And you can see that the text has some padding or something above it. I set `cell.Padding = 0` and `cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP` and set the Leading of the text to the same as the font size, but the weird spacing remains. Argh! Any thoughts there?

Comment: @Chris, I found that NoWrap = false when using FixedHeight, else text would overflow into next cell. But the FixedHeight approach is excellent. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Chris was very helpful in clipping cell content.  Below is my experience when implementing cell clipping using the approach mentioned by Chris. I am using iTextSharp 4.0.4.0.

**I found that the NoWrap property must always be set to false** in order to be able to wrap text OR to clip cell content if overflow needs to be hidden. In code below, based on the value of wrapText, cell contents would either get clipped (wrapText = false) or wrapped (wrapText = true). I am using iTextSharp version 4.0.4.0.

```
 //set the NoWrap to false, irrespective of whether you want to clip or wrap text
 cellEmpID.NoWrap =  false;
 cellAddress1.NoWrap = false;
 cellAddress2.NoWrap = false;

 //fixed height will clip cell content provided NoWrap is set to false.  
 //if NoWrap is set to true then text will overflow into next cell with fixed
 // height, which will make your pdf document look not-so-good.

 if (!wrapText)  
      {
        // set fixed height on all cells
        cellEmpID.FixedHeight = 10f;
        cellAddress1.FixedHeight = 10f;
        cellAddress2.FixedHeight =  10f;
     }
```

Comment: wrapping wont occur if a height is specified - so this worked for me